# Как найти/сделать драйвер Radeon 9600(r300) на Debian 6.0.5?

Tags: debian, драйвер, radeon

Помогите найти/сделать драйвер ATI Radeon на Debian 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вообще значит сделать? Может "поставить", установить, сконфигурировать, настроить.. или всё же самому сделать драйвер? хм сильно замахнулись, Мсьё.

Такие вопросы нужно задавать на специальных форумах по дистрибутиву, да и тем более зачем задавать и так всё есть уже, даже в [официальной документации](http://wiki.debian.org/ru/AtiHowTo) черкнули пару строк.

Comment: я и не против,что бы просто его поставить без всяких бубнов